# How to replace a table of a database from a restored database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I accidentally updated a table in an Azure SQL database, I created a restored backup of the database. I want to replace the table I updated with the table in the restored database. How can I do this?

Comment: Copy restored table into your "accidentally updated" database with a new name. Then write a query to update the table. What problems are you facing specifically?

Comment: I'd *guess* one problem is that they can't do cross database queries.

Comment: Yes as @ThomA correctly mentioned cross database queries are not allowed

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated#g-create-an-external-table-for-sql-server

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C73iDjnDn0o

Comment: How big is this table? Is it simpler to simply script out the data in it and then upsert, or create a new copy and then switch the two objects?

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126

Answer (score 1):

- You create an external table reference for Cross-database querying Azure SQL Databases.

I have used the
`select * into [RemoteDB02].dbo.remote_table_02 from [dbo].[RemoteDB]`

I get the following error:
[image]

I have reproduced Cross-database querying Azure SQL Databases for this we need SQL Login in master database and an SQL user in the remote database that references the created

- SQL Login in master database.
- Later this step we need to proceed and create the database scoped credential
- remote data source
- remote table
- external table reference and other settings that need to be configured before attempting to do cross-database queries in Azure SQL Database.

Thank you, @Fernando cobo for excellent article on Cross-database Query in Azure SQL Database

- Know more [Cross-database Query in Azure SQL
  Database](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126)

**Step1 :** I have create 2 databases
[image]
**Step2:** Create Login in the logical server
[image]
**Step 3:** Create a SQL User in the remote database
[image]
**Step 4:** Create a Master Key in the Origin Database
[image]

**Step 5:** Create a Database Scoped Credential in the origin database
[image]
**Step 6:** Creating the external data source origin database
[image]

**Step 7:** Create the table in the remote source

[image]
**Step 8:** Create the external table in the origin database
[image]
**Step 9:** Granting the RemoteDB user SELECT permissions on RemoteTable
[image]

- I have inserted some rescords into the **RemoteTable** You can query the remoteDB and OrdiginDB using the

[image]

[image]

As you can see that the originDB don't have the table, but it still references to remotDB as external table.
[image]

[image]